# Does using “controller as” syntax can help to find a scope of a controller in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I read about this new feature, very nice when you have nested controller, help to understand the binding element, where everything is coming from.

But I'm curious if this also can help me to find a specific controller scope, so no need to find controller by searching it by ID.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "finding a specific controller scope"? In which context would you like to find the controller scope?

Comment: lets say you have 2 controllers on page, one controller would like to update the second time each time someone click on the first controller. Can the first controller find the second one scope to update its info without firing event on scope?

Comment: In that cause the "controller as" syntax would help you only when the second controller is a parent of the first controller.